# Sorting Template Sections from inherited Base Templates

Tags: templates

Sitecore 9.1 installation.

I have a template called `Person`.

This template has a number of `Sections` defined in the Template itself, and some that are inherited from `Base Templates`.

One said `Base Template` is called **DivisionPicker**. I want it to appear immediately after `Quick Info`, so I edited the `Section` *Division* inside **DivisionPicker** like so:

[image]

And saved everything. This did not alter the sort order of the *Division* Section inside existing instances of the `Person` template.

**Question**

How can I alter the order of `Sections` belonging to `Base Templates` inside instances of a given `Template`?

Comment: What is the sort order of the other field sections in the Person template? I sometimes find that sort orders less than 100 don't seem to work. Also, if some field sections' sort orders are coming from standard values, they may not work quite right.

Comment: They are all 100-150-200-250 etc. I will try to put the `Division` Sortorder to 110, and everything else before to values between 110 and 150.

Comment: This did the trick: Sortorder apparently MUST be higher than 100 in order for it to work. Phrase it as an answer and I will immediately accept it.

Comment: Just to further on this; I always suspected `__Sortorder` to be sorted internally as a string or somesuch - definitely not as a numeric field as one might suspect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I often find that field section sort order does not work across inherited templates if the sort orders are not greater than 100.

Try updating the sort orders of the field sections on your Person template to be > 100 and see if they merge better.